# Add a column in existing table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have a table `A::B` (`A` is the namespace) in rails. I want to add a column `name` in `B`. I am writing this command :

```
rails g migration AddNameToA::B name:string
```

I don't think `AddNameToA::B` is right. What should the command be?

Comment: You can create migration like this `rails g migration add_column_to_a_b name:string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
rails g migration add_name_to_a_b name:string
```

Edit #1:

As Marek Lipka said, string is default type so:

```
rails g migration add_name_to_a_b name
```

will also work

Comment: Your answer is correct. It worth noting that string is default type so `rails g migration add_name_to_b name` would also work.

Comment: Since table B is in namespace A, isn't there any need to write A in migration command?

Comment: @Hellboy: Yes, we have to mention A. I thought you are referring to an association by A::B. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
rails g migration AddColumnNameToUser name:string
```

here, I added a new column named 'name' in **user** table. For better understanding go to [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
rails g migration add_name_to_B name:string
```

or

```
rails g migration add_name_to_b name:string
```

This is the proper name for your migration file